# Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run a java program.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:"

I have a book folder in which I have a file Goo.java

```
package book;
import cert.*;

class Goo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Sludge s = new Sludge();
        s.testIt();
    }
}
```

I have a cert folder in which i have a file Sludge.java:

```
package cert;
public class Sludge
{
    public void testIt()
    {
        System.out.println("Sludge");
    }
}
```

I have both the folders (book and cert) under `D:\studies` and my classpath includes:

> .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib;D:\studies\book;D:\studies\cert;D:\studies

When I try to run the file `Goo.java`, I get the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

What am I doing wrong here??

Thanks,
Priyesh T.

Comment: Can you show us the command you are using to execute the java?

Comment: i am executing the java by using the command: java Goo

Comment: The folders should include `Goo.class` and `Sludge.class`. Please verify, that both java files have been compiled.

Comment: both the folders book and cert have the Goo.class and Sludge.class files respectively.

Comment: using this command also gave the same error.

Comment: @thinksteep: The class is in a package...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I deleted my comment. It doesn't make sense for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Goo` class is in package `book`, so you should be running:

```
java book.Goo
```

Run it from the directory *containing* the book directory. So for example, you might run:

```
> javac book\Goo.java cert\Sludge.java
> java book.Goo
```

`book.Goo` is the fully-qualified name of the `Goo` class.

Comment: could you explain me why it didn't work when i used just Java Goo? i am confused that even after declaring the path to the class file in my class path, why did i get this error?

Comment: @PriyeshTungare: Because `Goo` isn't the fully-qualified class name, and you've got to give the fully-qualified class name... You don't put a path to the class file itself in your class path; you put a path to the root of your class file folder structure (i.e. the parent of `book` in this case) into your classpath.